# Prove that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ exists and finite, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$ doesn't exist then L is an integer

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> > Let $f$ be a continuous function on $(0, \infty)$ s.t $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}f(x) = L$ exists and finite, but $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \lfloor f(x) \rfloor$ doesn't exist. Prove that L is an integer .

I tried to use the fact that for each $\epsilon >0$ there is $x_o$ that for each $x>x_0$ : $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon$. and suppose negatively that L is not an integer and get a contradiction.

Thats by choosing such an epsilon that guarantees that $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor=\lfloor L\rfloor$ when $x>x_0$, or any other combination that tells us $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\lfloor f(x)\rfloor = \text{exists}$

I didn't know how to continue from here, or find such an epsilon.

NOTE: $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$ is the floor function.

Comment: If $n < L< n+1$, then there is a small $\delta$ so that for all $x$ big enough we have $n+ \delta < f(x) < n+1-\delta$. (1. How to find that $\delta$? 2. What is $[f(x)]$ then?)

Comment: @John I think you meant we get: $ n- \delta < f(x) < n + 1 + \delta $, because $ L-\epsilon < f(x) < L+ \epsilon $

Comment: I edited your title and question to use a notation for the floor function that is more obvious.

Comment: @RoryDaulton thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to do a proof by contradiction. Assume the opposite, that $L$ is not an integer. Note that because $L$ is not an integer, $\lfloor L\rfloor<L<\lceil L\rceil$. Because $f(x)\to L$ as $x\to\infty$, we can choose $\varepsilon=\min\{L-\lfloor L\rfloor, \lceil L\rceil-L\}$ such that there exists an $M$ such that for all $x>M$, $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

If $L-\lfloor L\rfloor\le \lceil L\rceil-L$, then $\varepsilon=L-\lfloor L\rfloor$ and

$$|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\\\Rightarrow\lfloor L\rfloor-L<f(x)-L<L-\lfloor L\rfloor\le\lceil L\rceil-L\\
\Rightarrow\lfloor L\rfloor<f(x)<\lceil L\rceil$$

If $L-\lfloor L\rfloor> \lceil L\rceil-L$, then $\varepsilon=\lceil L\rceil-L$ and

$$|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\\\Rightarrow \lfloor L\rfloor-L<L-\lceil L\rceil<f(x)-L<\lceil L\rceil-L\\
\Rightarrow\lfloor L\rfloor<f(x)<\lceil L\rceil$$

And so, for all $x>M$, $f(x)\in(\lfloor L\rfloor,\lceil L\rceil)$. Then $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor = \lfloor L\rfloor$ for all $x>M$, and $\lim_x\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$ exists and is equal to $\lfloor L\rfloor$.

Comment: What do you mean it will reside in $(\lfloor L\rfloor, \lceil L\rceil)?$ could you elaborate ?

Comment: @Firas: Because $f$ converges to $L$, we can pick any $\varepsilon$ and eventually $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ will hold. If we choose $\varepsilon=\min\{L-\lfloor L\rfloor, \lceil L\rceil-L\}$, then it will eventually hold that $f(x)\in(\lfloor L\rfloor, \lceil L\rceil)$.

Comment: @Firas: Would you like me to edit the answer to explain it in more detail?

Comment: That would be more helpful. because I got confused between the floor and ceiling function, and I tried to choose the min of what u suggested as an epsilon and tried to do $ L-\epsilon < f(x) < L+ \epsilon $ but couldn't get information from that.

Comment: @Firas: I have edited the answer.

Comment: thank you, I got it. would this solution work after the edit in the question? which means the questions relates only to the floor function?

Comment: @Firas: The edit only affected how the question looks, not the content of it. This answer still applies.